# Can we restrict the window created by a chrome extension to be unmovable and change size on the go

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon-webextensions

Using `chrome.windows.create(...)` in `background.js`, I'm creating 2 window popups.

The requirements for different conditions are:

1. The 2 windows are sticked together - it means if one of the window is moved, let's say 10 units to the left, then the other window should also be moved 10 units to the left, simultaneously.
2. The 2 windows are unmovable - if the user tries to move the window around, it shouldn't be allowed to do so. If this isn't allowed, for some reason, then any workaround would also do.

Comment: "it means if one of the window is moved" and "The 2 windows are unmovable" contradict each other. Please give us more information about the extension you're programming and what it does. BTW, I upvoted your question, because someone else downvoted it without explaining why, which is not helpful IMHO.

Comment: Thank you for the upvote. Sorry for the confusion. I tried to give a clarity by mentioning "the requirements for different conditions". For one scenario requirement 1 is required, and for another, requirement 2 is required.

Comment: Is it not possible to split one Window into two with an iframe?

Comment: It's probably not possible out of the box, because it would allow malicious extensions to show very intrusive ads. You'll have to use [Native Messaging](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/apps/nativeMessaging/). I'm still curious what exactly you're trying to accomplish, and why.

Comment: @ThomasMueller For the 1st condition, 2 windows are being pop open and each of them has different pages loaded and both are codependent. For user convenience, they need to be sticked together so that if the user wants to adjust the position of the popups, both of them are adjusted together.

Comment: @ThomasMueller For a separate functionality, the user shouldn't be allowed to move the window and the popup needs to stay where it's already placed. So, even if a user tried to move the window, the functionality would be restricted.

Comment: I've already coded up a workaround for the 1st condition but it's buggy. If the bugs are fixed, the second condition shouldn't be a problem to implement then. If I come up with a clean solution, I'll post that as an answer. If you have any reference solution, please share the same. Thank you.